# How to run a script over several files

Tags: python, pandas, file

I am trying to create a dataframe with the filenames from a folder. After that, the idea is reading each row of that dataframe, identify it was a file, create a dataframe with it and run the rest of the script to replace a column for a new value (this last part is already done and working properly).

So, first I read the files and put them on a list:

```
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
files
```

And then, I create the dataframe:

```
df_file = pd.DataFrame (files, columns = ['Filename'])
```

At this point is when I get stuck. Now that I have my dataframe with my filenames. How can Python identify every row as a file and save the data on a dataframe?

PS.: I am doing this because my old boss told me so. But the instructions wasn't really specific and I am lost.

Thanks!

Comment: What type of file are you looking at? xlsx?

Comment: Yes! It's a xlsx file.

Comment: My answer below should help then!

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure on what type of files you are looking to identify, if they are xlsx files, the following should help:

```
import os
import pandas as pd


# You don't need to identify the current path
# path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir()


df_file = pd.DataFrame(files, columns=['Filename'])
# You are right up to this point

# Read all the rows in this main dataframe
for file in df_file['Filename']:
    # If it is an excel file, proceed to run functions on it
    # If it is a different type of file (e.g. csv) just swap "xlsx" out for "csv"
    if "xlsx" in file:
        df = pd.read_excel(file)
        # Continue...
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help